# Deleting commits with SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to Git, and I only understand how to use it with SourceTree (a little bit)

My branch-graph is this:

```
 o   Commit E is origin/test and (local) master
 |
 | o Commit D is origin/master
 | |
 | o Commit C
 | |
 | o Commit B
 |/
 o   Commit A
 |
```

Now, I want to:

- delete the Commits D, C and B
- move the origin/master to Commit E
- delete the origin/test branch tag

But I don't find the right buttons and commands in SourceTree.

Comment: That's why I hate Git desktop clients.

Comment: If you only understand it with SourceTree, it is unlikely you will ever understand Git properly. I suggest you take the initial productivity hit and get familiar with Git via the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is push your (local) master branch to `origin` with `--force` to signify that you want to rewrite history.
i.e : you know your changes will cause the origin/master branch to loose history (the 3 commits B, C, D) and you don't care.

I don't know sourcetree well enough to tell you if such an operation is possible, the GUI is evolving all the time and they add new functionnality to support more operation every month, but you could always open the git console from sourcetree (at least until 1.3 there was an icon to do that) and enter :

`git push --force origin master`

This will push your (local) master  branch to its tracking branch (which should be origin/master).

N.B: I don't know how you configured your SourceTree, but if you rely on https to communicate with the server you might have to enter a login/password.

EDIT 1:

If you also want to remove the origin/test you can do this by right-cliking the branch (under remotes)in sourceTree and selecting delete :

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/65053/how-do-you-remove-branches-from-source-tree

EDIT 2:

Apparently a GUI option for `push --force` was/will be added to version 1.7

As a more general answer : Stackoverflow isn't google. SourceTree is a free commercial software backed by Atlassian. They have support for you. They have an ok'ish manual and a user base sufficient not to be the first newbe to wonder how to do X. Just google it.

Answer (score 0):

No clue how to do this with SourceTree. As others said: take the command line:

```
git checkout master               # master points at COMMIT E
git push -f origin master:master  # forced push to origin so that masters are equal
git push origin :test             # delete origin/test
```

No buttons needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is resolved but faced a similar issue and used Source tree to solve as follows:
You can use "Reverse Commit..." option (when you right click that commit) on each commit starting from the latest commit D. Do not push any change and one by one use reverse commit for C and B. After these 3 reverses, your code on origin/master branch will be same as commit A. Now push the changes to remote repo(branch origin/master). Merge origin/test to origin/master. Now origin/master is at commit E. Push this and when you are on origin/master branch you can delete origin/test branch.
P.S.: Only thing is you will see revert commits on the branch but the code will be clean.

Answer (score 0):

## **How to Delete a Commit from Source Tree**

1. Select the commit you want to go back to
2. Right-click and choose the option “Reset current branch to this commit”
3. In using mode choose “Mixed - keep working copy but reset index”
4. Select your branch and choose option Push to → {branch}
5. Make sure Force Push option is checked
6. Push your changes

[git](/questions/tagged/git)[sourcetree](/questions/tagged/sourcetree)